# Can't run entire stored procedure using PHP and PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm trying to run a stored procedure using PHP and PDO, and I ran into an issue where not all statements in the SP are run. For my example, I tried to do 320 simple insert statements, and PDO only got through 317 of them.

Here's the SP:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE TestSP
AS 
BEGIN 
insert into TestTable values (1)
-- ~314 rows later...
insert into TestTable values (316)
insert into TestTable values (317)
-- PDO stops here
insert into TestTable values (318)
insert into TestTable values (319)
insert into TestTable values (320)
END
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
$connection = new PDO(
  "sqlsrv:server=localhost ; Database=TestDb",
  "username",
  "password"
);
$stmt = $connection->prepare('EXEC TestSP');
$stmt->execute();
```

When I run the same EXEC statement using an MSSQL connection, the entire SP runs.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Please ask questions if I need to provide more information.

FYI I did try "Call TestSP" and it would not work at all.

**Edit:** tried a script with a loop (I'm pretty new to scrpting in SQL)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM   sys.objects
           WHERE  object_id = Object_id(N'TestSP')
                  AND type IN ( N'P', N'PC' ))
  DROP PROCEDURE TestSP
GO

CREATE  PROCEDURE TestSP
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE
    @counter int

SET @counter = 1
WHILE (@counter <= 500)
    BEGIN
        insert into TestTable values (@counter)
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    END
END
GO
```

Makes it a bit easier to test. Funny thing is I only got 108 rows from PDO, still got the whole thing from MSSQL.

Comment: How long does the SP take to run? Perhaps you have reached PHP's time limit.

Comment: maybe a timeout issue on the pdo connection?

Comment: Nope, runs in a few seconds, no other issues, returns true.

Comment: Have you seen the way the stored procedures are called on this link? http://trentrichardson.com/2011/08/10/making-sense-of-stored-procedures-with-php-pdo-and-sqlsrv/

Comment: I don't see what from that example could help me. The only real difference I see is that it accepts arguments and has a return value, whereas my SP does not.

Comment: OK, it looks like **Ateszki** was on the right track. When I used the code from the trentrichardson.com link with some minor modifications, it inserted all of the rows through PDO. I will post the script I used after the 6-8 hours I have to wait :-P

Comment: I hate waiting. Basically, use "CALL" when running the SP from PHP, and don't forget closeCursor() after execute().